# Java Spring Boot: Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

A little new to the Java Spring Boot flavor of webservices -- so please be gentle. ***Why do most Spring Boot Controller examples not show any exceptions being captured?*** I see some of my fellow developers do this a lot. And the answer is: it's a common convention. But why. Am I missing a key concept of web services created using Spring Boot?

**For example**:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sampleEndpoint/v1/myEndpoint", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> myEndpoint(@RequestBody MyEndpointRequest myEndpointRequest) {
    
     MyEndpointResponse response = someService.myEndpoint(myEndpointRequest);
     return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I would think, with respects to the architecture you would add AT LEAST a try/catch block with say some logging, and throw a new exception with the exceptions message:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sampleEndpoint/v1/myEndpoint", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> myEndpoint(@RequestBody MyEndpointRequest myEndpointRequest) {


  try{  
       MyEndpointResponse response = someService.myEndpoint(myEndpointRequest);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

  }catch(Exception ex){
    //Your favorite logger:
    log.error("STACK_TRACE: {}", StaticClass.stackTraceToString(ex));

    //throw exception for calling or consuming system/application:
    throw new MiscException(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

A couple of things to give context to this question (observation):

- Use multiple data sources: a couple of databases, and some other web services (gives our client a one stop place to get their data.
- Using this webservice with potentially 4 different client side /presentation layer type of applications.
- My team would like to capture unexpected exceptions emanating from the data sources we tap into...and log them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's up to developer to implement catch of exceptions mechanism. But it's a good practise to define exceptions types and error codes/messages for that. Let's say you have an endpoint which fetch product with id, but there is no product with that id, in that case client will receive `http 500` code with `internal server error` message. This will confuse users and also developers, what was the real cause of that error.

So prevent those, you can get help from `@ControllerAdvice` annotation, which will allow to apply exception handlers to more than one or all controllers.
First you will define your custom exceptions like :

```
public class ProductNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public ProductNotFoundException(Long id) {

        super(String.format("Product with id %d not found", id));
    }
}
```

and then you can define your `ControllerAdvice` class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

 @ExceptionHandler(ProductNotFound.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleProductNotFoundException(
        ProductNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        body.put("message", "Product not found");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there can be many ways to implement exception handling but let me tell you mine the controller must be clear and isolated from any of such conventions and the exception handlings and any logic you want the controller to execute must be inside an implementation class which handles what logic your request must perform.

Also,
Spring Boot encourages developers to delegate exception handling to a centralized mechanism, such as using a global exception handler annotated with @ControllerAdvice. This helps maintain a cleaner and more modular code structure.

- Unnecessary Code Duplication:
  Placing try/catch blocks in each controller method can lead to code duplication. Centralized exception handling allows you to handle exceptions consistently across multiple controllers.
- Clearer Code Flow:
  Focusing on the primary logic in the controller methods enhances readability. Exception handling can be separated from the core functionality, making the code easier to understand at a glance.
- Consistency Across Controllers:
  Following a convention of centralized exception handling ensures a consistent approach across all controllers in your application.

However, it's generally recommended to keep the controllers concise and delegate exception handling to a dedicated component. Here's a basic example:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sampleEndpoint/v1/myEndpoint", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> myEndpoint(@RequestBody MyEndpointRequest myEndpointRequest) {
    try {
        MyEndpointResponse response = someService.myEndpoint(myEndpointRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the exception for troubleshooting
        log.error("Exception in myEndpoint:", e);
        // Customize the response based on the exception if needed
        return new ResponseEntity<>("An error occurred.", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```